# Show wp_next_scheduled in local time

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, local

I try almost everything.. but `wp_next_scheduled('hook_task')` always return time 1 hours back (my local timezone is UTC + 1, task scheduler is set for run each minute).

I try this conversions:

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',wp_next_scheduled('hook_task'));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',current_time(wp_next_scheduled('hook_task')));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',current_time(wp_next_scheduled('hook_task'), 1));
```

but everything return **19:05**
when next function return correct local time **20:05**:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',current_time("timestamp"));
```

`date_default_timezone_get()` return **UTC**.
How to get correct local datetime 20:05 for next planned run?

### Testing

**I've tried based on your answers:**

1) First test

```
echo 'ACTUAL:  ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s',current_time("timestamp")) . '<br>';
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bratislava'));
echo 'WITH TZ: ' . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br>';
$time = wp_next_scheduled('hook_task');
$date = new DateTime("@$time", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bratislava'));
echo 'RESULT:  ' . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I tried also this: `$date = new DateTime("@$time", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Bangkok'));` but regardless I set as timezone it always return the same result.

*And result:*

```
ACTUAL:  2015-12-12 22:45:10  // correct
WITH TZ: 2015-12-12 22:45:10  // correct
RESULT:  2015-12-12 21:45:39  // incorrect
```

**2) Correct solution**

```
$time = wp_next_scheduled('hook_task');
echo 'RESULT2: ' . get_date_from_gmt( date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) );
```

*And result:*

```
RESULT2: 2015-12-12 22:45:39  // correct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress uses GMT timestamp to reschedule the task every time it's been executed, so in order to convert the timestamp in your local one you need to add the offset for your local time from GMT time.

Luckily there's a function called [`get_date_from_gmt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_date_from_gmt) that

> Simply adds the value of the `gmt_offset` option

Here's the code:

```
$time = wp_next_scheduled('hook_task');

echo get_date_from_gmt( date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) );
```

Comment: Sorry, but this not working :( .. check my updated response.

Comment: @Atiris I've changed my answer

Comment: Many thanks @d79 .. now it is working.. It was not so easy :)